# Is there a short form of "vice versa"

Tags: abbreviations

Does "Vice versa" have a common abbreviation / short form? I'm a lazy typer when it comes to notes to myself.

Comment: As it's latin, wouldn't it be more like v.v.?

Comment: Although @NVZ's answer gives abbreviations drawn from authoritative sources, you asked for *common* abbreviations, and there is no abbreviation common enough that I, personally, would have recognized it before today.  On the other hand, if you're writing notes only for yourself, then why does it matter?

Comment: "Questions that can be answered using commonly-available references are off-topic" So... ALL questions here are thus off topic - I think someone needs to reword their rules. Oh, the irony.

Answer (score 3):

I have occasionally seen **"vv"** for "vice versa".
Sometimes "vv" is also used to mean "verses" as in "chorus +3 vv" meaning "chorus and then three verses"

Answer (score 3):

According to [TFD](http://acronyms.thefreedictionary.com/vice+versa) and more, **V/V** or **VV**.

According to [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/v.v.) and more, **v.v**.

According to [Collins](http://www.memidex.com/vice-versa) and more, **vv**

So there  is no fixed way I guess.